# Choosing a graphics card for Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am in the process of obtaining the appropriate hardware for Gazebo. Do you know if the following graphics cards will work well with Gazebo?

NVIDIA Quadro 600

NVIDIA Quadro 2000

I would like some confirmation before I make purchases. Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3658/choosing-a-graphics-card-for-gazebo/) by [mchapman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/405/mchapman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

found some reference benchmarks for reference:

- [quadro 2000](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Quadro+2000)
- [quadro 600](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Quadro+600)
- [gtx 650](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce+GTX+650)

In addition, from specs on Nvidia site, the memory bandwidth of [Quadro 2000 (@41.5 GB/sec)](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadro-2000-us.html) is about half of [GTX 650 (@80.0 GB/sec)](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650/specifications), and [Quadro 600 (@25.6 GB/sec)](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadro-600-us.html) will be about half of Quadro 2000.  Since a lot of the simulation work is getting the images off of these cards, one can probably expect performance to scale accordingly as well.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mchapman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/405/mchapman/) on 2013-07-19**:
Thank you very much for your help!

**Comment by [mchapman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/405/mchapman/) on 2013-07-19**:
Thank you very much for your help!